# Django Rest Framework Test API Response Assertion

Tags: django, api, testing, django-rest-framework

I've an issues finding the ideal way to test the API endpoint developed in Django with the Django Rest Framework. I'm using the integrated APITestCase and performing the request like this:

```
response = self.client.get('/resources')
```

The official documentation (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing) states that is better to use `response.data` instaed of `response.content`. My model includes a `DateTimeField` field and the `response.data` looks like this:

```
{'id': 1, 'issued': datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

Where as the real response in a browser looks like this:

```
{"id": 1, "issued": "2014-05-03T00:00:00Z"}
```

So I'm not sure how to assert that those two are equal!?

Answer (score 0):

For assert that those two are equal you can use

```
`self.assertEqual( wanted_datetime,'got_datetime')`
```

and to compare datetime in django you can look at following link.

1.[Django unit testing with date/time-based objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042900/django-unit-testing-with-date-time-based-objects)

2.[How to compare dates in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798812/how-to-compare-dates-in-django)