# How to pass context when testing deletion of an instance?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got a couple models, `Car` and `CertifyRequest`. When a `Car` instance is created, modified *or deleted* I need to create a `CertifyRequest`, which in turn needs to be manually approved. The `CertifyRequest` instance contains the time it was created.

I've tested creating and modifying by injecting `context={"now": …}` into a `CarSerializer` instance, but I can't figure out how to do the equivalent when deleting:

1. Delete requests are never passed to the serializer, so I can't access the context in the same way.
2. I can override `destroy` in the `ModelViewSet` and use `get_serializer_context` within it, but

   1. I can't seem to pass the serializer to the `ModelViewSet` instance and
   2. [the implementation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/cdb8a3c3c86bbb74f17f8880c52000602b015ed4/rest_framework/generics.py#L132-L140) returns a completely different context anyway.
3. I do not want to use a horrible hack like an optional query parameter or testing that the time is "close to" the current test client time.

The hack I'm using currently is to set an extra `now` property on the `Request` which I pass to the view, and to look for that inside `destroy`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Django's `timezone.now()` in your view to get the current time, you can mock that method to return a specific time in your tests and assert against that.

```
def test_destroy_car():
    client = APIClient()
    @mock.patch("application.views.timezone.now") as now:
        destroy_time = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 23, 11, 2, 0)
        now.return_value = destroy_time
        response = client.destroy("/api/car/12345/")
        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT, "The request to delete did not return a 204 response"
        certify_request = CertifyRequest.objects.order_by("id").last()
        assert certify_request.created_at == destroy_time, "CertifyRequest destroy time is incorrect"
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to inject the value rather than mocking. Mocking relies on the test "knowing" the implementation, as in this example where you need to know which specific function to mock, so it results in a more brittle tests.

Comment: I don't think modifying the view/serializer with specific code to support your tests (a custom property on the request) is much better.  The way I see it, your tests needs to know which specific request property it needs to mock for the view to inject the value.  Similar questions about testing with date/time objects use mocking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042900/django-unit-testing-with-date-time-based-objects.

Comment: Sure, that's why I consider my current solution a hack, and that's the main reason for asking. But after using mocks and injections I much prefer the latter.